# some problems in EditText in ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, android-edittext

I am very new in android and currently working on a simple andriod apps. I'm writing a listview and I want to put some EditText and textViews into it. My idea is to put one textview then followed by one edittext in every items on listview. Then I can get the values from edittext to make some calculations and get the result.
I can now make a listview and also handle the calculations. But I really cannot make the listview by my own.
I have been searched google for any instructions to make this but I cannot find any good resources. Can anyone please give me some sample codes so that I can have a guide to follow...
Thank you for that

Here are my partial code

```
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    setContentView(R.layout.infmain);


    ListView lstView;

    lstView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    ArrayAdapter<String> listadapter = new ArrayAdapter<String> (this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,list);
    lstView.setAdapter(listadapter);

    Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.planets_spinner);


    Integer[] items = new Integer[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11,
            12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18 };
    ArrayAdapter<Integer> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Integer>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);


    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new Spinner.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView adapterView, View view,
                int position, long id) {

        }

        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView arg0) {

        }
    });
}
```

I am looking some sample codes that did similar things to me.
So I can read and learn from the codes.
thanks

Comment: Explain a bit. **cannot make the listview by my own.**

Comment: post what you have tried yet?

Comment: ok good but you need to create custom adpter

Answer (score 0):

Default adapter and view wont do as you as you have used in your code.

You need to have a separate xml for your rows. And inflate that row with a custom adapter.

In your rowview just add a an edittext below textview and that should work.

Answer (score 0):

ok make a new layout named `img_row_layout` and copy this code to it

```
 ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/img"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/img"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dist"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"


   android:layout_below="@id/name"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dip"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/img"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:textSize="8dp"
        android:textStyle="italic" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The layout shown above is quite trivial and we don’t need to explain it. Then we have to modify the custom adapter in order to handle the images and the holder class. The holder class becomes:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View v = convertView;
     
    PlanetHolder holder = new PlanetHolder();
     
    // First let's verify the convertView is not null
    if (convertView == null) {
        // This a new view we inflate the new layout
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.img_row_layout, null);
        // Now we can fill the layout with the right values
        TextView tv = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.name);
        TextView distView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.dist);
        ImageView img = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.img);
         
        holder.planetNameView = tv;
        holder.distView = distView;
        holder.img = img;
         
        v.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
        holder = (PlanetHolder) v.getTag();
     
    System.out.println("Position ["+position+"]");
    Planet p = planetList.get(position);
    holder.planetNameView.setText(p.getName());
    holder.distView.setText("" + p.getDistance());
     
    holder.img.setImageResource(p.getIdImg());
     
    return v;
}
```

[similar example 1](http://www.caveofprogramming.com/frontpage/articles/custom-listview-with-imageview-and-textview-in-android/)
[Similat Example 2](http://theopentutorials.com/tutorials/android/listview/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-arrayadapter/)